# Select where join table contains specific values

Tags: join, plsql

Let's imagine I have the following tables:

```
Table: Jobs
JobID | Desc
1  |  Desc1
2  |  Desc2
3  |  Desc3

Table: Docs
JobId | DocId | Filename
1     | 1     | File1
1     | 2     | File2 
2     | 3     | File1
3     | 4     | File2
```

Now I want to select the jobs out of the `Jobs` table with its `desc` which have `File1` and `File2` in the Docs Table which is here `JobId=1`. How should my SQL Statement look like?

**UPDATE:**

I have tried the following:

```
Select * 
from Jobs j 
inner join Docs d 
   on j.JobId = d.jobId 
where Filename = 'File1' and Filename='File2'
```

which is wrong. It returns nothing, because there is no record in `Docs` which has the `File1` and `File2` in the field.

```
Select * 
from Jobs j 
inner join Docs d 
   on j.JobId = d.jobId 
where Filename = 'File1' or Filename='File2'
```

which is wrong. It returns the Jobs `1`,`2`,`3` because they fill this criteria.

What I need:

From Table `Jobs`:

```
1  |  Desc1
```

because it has a record in the `Docs` table containing `File1` and another containing `File2`.

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You see the schema and sample data in the question in the example. Expected output is also given. I have not written current output, because it is wrong anyway.

Comment: You didnt put expected output in the same format as the sample data. Your description is vague and ambiguous. You need to show us what you have try so we dont repeat the effort you made.

Comment: Your requirements are unclear with contradicting claims

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Where are the contradicting claims?

Comment: Is english your native language?  Because I cant understand what you need. That is why I ask you to show me how your result should looks like. Otherwise we will be wasting our time guessing what you need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select j.JobID , j.Desc
from Jobs j 
inner join Docs d 
   on j.JobId = d.jobId 
where Filename IN  ('File1', 'File2')

GROUP BY j.JobID , j.Desc
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT FileName)  = 2
```

For only those job with only those two files use conditional aggregation.

```
Select j.JobID , j.Desc
from Jobs j 
inner join Docs d 
   on j.JobId = d.jobId 

GROUP BY j.JobID , j.Desc
HAVING COUNT( DISTINCT CASE WHEN FileName IN ('File1', 'File2') 
                            THEN FileName 
                       END)  = 2
   AND COUNT(FileName) = 2
```

Comment: Thanks. This works. If I want to just have the `Jobs` which have this two  files and nothing more, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from DOCS inner join jobs on jobs.jobID=docs.jobID ORDER BY filename
```

PS I'm not that good with databases.

Comment: This is not an answer to my question

Comment: Improve your question with expected output so we can know what you need